# Show polynomial function is infinitely differentialble

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let for $\alpha=(\alpha_0,...,\alpha_n)\in\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ the polynomial $p_\alpha :\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be given by $p_\alpha(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_kz^k$.

> Show that with the identification $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$ with $x+iy\cong (x,y)$, the function $p_\alpha$ is element of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$.

I read such things can be shown using Taylor's theorem but how can I apply it here?

Comment: Does $\alpha$ have anything to do with $p_\alpha$?

Comment: Can you prove that $z$ is $C^\infty$? How about $z^2$?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Yes, it is the coefficient, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 6):

I leave the details to you.

It is not very difficult (and very useful) to prove that:

1. All constant functions are $C^\infty$.
2. If $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ and $g:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ are $C^\infty$ (in the sense given in the OP question), then $fg$  and $f+g$ are also $C^\infty$.
3. $f(z)=z$ is $C^\infty$, so $f_k(z)=z^k$ is $C^\infty$.
4. Any polynomial $p$ is $C^\infty$. Clearly, by 0. and 1. (product), every monomial $a_kz^k$ is $C^\infty$. Using $1.$ (sum) and induction, every polynomial, which is a finite sum of monomial, is $C^\infty$.

Comment: You probably want to prove $C^{\infty}$ in 1 for $a f$ with $a$ any constant as well.  Otherwise, this is definitely the easiest path.

Comment: @exodu5: This is actually contained in 1.

Comment: That's true only if in 2 you prove the constant function $C^{\infty}$.  It's very little work either way (it's the same work phrased differently), but you need it to get to polynomials.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I lack intuition why any polynomial $p$ is $C^\infty$, if I differentiate a $\mathbb{R}^2$ function it vanishes! Also, how does 3) follow from 1) and 2)???

Comment: @ex0du5: you're right! I'll edit

Comment: @sj134: why should a ${\mathbb R}^2$ function vanish when differentiated? Yes $3)$ (now 4) after editing) follows from the previous point. It is standard process in calculus/analysis; you did it when you proved that polynomials of a real variable are continuous and/or differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

EDIT: I mistakenly thought the series was infinite, and not a polynomial. I thought the question was about showing that any complex-analytic function was $C^{\infty}$ when seen as a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to itself, under the equivalence $x+ iy \rightarrow (x,y)$. My proof below refers to this case.

If $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is complex-differentiable, i.e., analytic in a region $R$ , then the partials $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ exist and are continuous. Since a complex-analytic function $f(z)$ is infinitely-differentiable, the same goes for all partials of all orders, i.e., $u_{xx}, u_{xy}, u_{yx}, u_{yy}, u_{xxy},....$  are all infinitely-differentiable .Moreover, $$f'(z)=u_x+iv_x $$. With the identification $x+iy \rightarrow (x,y)$ , we get $$f'(z)=u_x+iv_x =\nabla f(x,y)\rightarrow (u_x,v_x) $$ , where $\nabla$ is the gradient, i.e., the total derivative of $f$. Now, we have from above that both $u_x, v_x$ both exist and are continuous, so that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable. Now we can induct on this result (using the fact from above that all partials exist and are continuous/differentiable, i.e., $C^{\infty}$) to differentiate $f$ any number of times to get the result we want.

Another result you can use that is more abstract and is more of a hand-waving result is that $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R^2$ are diffeomorphic as manifolds (actually, using the map in your post), so that every function differentiable in one manifold is (after change of coordinates given by the diffeomorphism) differentiable in its diffeomorphic image.

Comment: Everything is correct but I wonder if it is adapted to the OP's knowledge. If he knows all the theory on complex-analytic functions, he can probably show that polynomials are smooth.

Comment: @Taladris: I was considering an argument similar to yours, but I thought there may be some issue with the infinite sum of smooth functions being smooth. I thought it may involve some limit-taking which may be obscure. Let's wait and see what ( if anything ) the OP has to say. Still, it may help some others.

Comment: Infinite sum? The question is about a polynomial function. Did I miss something?

Comment: Well, the OP is describing an infinite Taylor series as a polynomial, so I'm not 100% on what s/he means.

Comment: @Taladris: My bad, I saw an infinite sum for some reason, my mistake. I just edited to reflect my mistaken assumption. Talk about using a tank to kill a fly.